# Find analytical expression for t as a function of x for first maximum in a periodic function

Tags: maximum

I have the following expression:

```
3 Csc[2 \[Pi] x t] Sin[4 \[Pi] x t]^2
```

I know the first maximum occurs at:

```
t = ArcCos[Sqrt[2/3]]/(2 \[Pi] x)
```

But how can I show this using Mathematica for x>0 and t>0?

Comment: Your expression online depends on the product `x t`. Introduce a new variable `xt` and check `expr'[xt]==0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start from the determination of the period by

```
FunctionPeriod[3 Csc[2 \[Pi] x t] Sin[4 \[Pi] x t]^2, t]
```

> `1/x`

Now we find its maximums on the range from `0` to `1/x`, making use of the necessary condition of an extremum and the sufficient condition of a maximum in terms of the sign of the second derivative

```
Reduce[D[3 Csc[2 \[Pi] x t] Sin[4 \[Pi] x t]^2, t] == 0 && 
D[3 Csc[2 \[Pi] x t] Sin[4 \[Pi] x t]^2, {t, 2}] < 0 && t > 0 && 
t <= 1/x && x > 0, t] // ToRadicals
```

> `x > 0 && (t == 3/(4 x) || t == ArcTan[Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]]/(\[Pi] x) || t == ArcTan[Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[6]]]/(\[Pi] x))`

Taking into account `x>0`,  we find the smallest point of the maximum by

```
Min[{3/4, ArcTan[Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]]/\[Pi],ArcTan[Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[6]]]/\[Pi]}]
```

> `ArcTan[Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]]/\[Pi]`

Last, but not least,

```
FullSimplify[ArcCos[Sqrt[2/3]]/(2 \[Pi]) - ArcTan[Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]]/\[Pi]]
```

> `0`

Comment: Thank you very much for this extremely elegant answer. It is still interesting, however, that Mathematica produces the ArcTan result, rather than the simpler looking ArcCos expression.

Comment: A slight improvement: `FullSimplify[
 Min[{3/4/x, ArcTan[Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]]/\[Pi]/x, 
   ArcTan[Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[6]]]/\[Pi]/x}], Assumptions -> x > 0]` produces `ArcTan[Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]]/(\[Pi] x)`.

Comment: @sje1g13: `LeafCount[ArcCos[Sqrt[2/3]]/(2 \[Pi])]` equals `15`, `LeafCount[ArcTan[Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]]/\[Pi]]` equals `18`.

Comment: `Length[ArcCos[Sqrt[2/3]]/(2 \[Pi])]` equals `3` and `Length[ArcTan[Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]]/\[Pi]]` equals `2`. Maybe, this is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer. Introduce a new variable xt and check Maximize[expr[xt],xt]

```
expr = 3 Csc[2 \[Pi] x t] Sin[4 \[Pi] x t]^2 /. x -> xt /t
NMaximize[expr,xt]  (*{4.6188, {xt -> 0.0979566}}*)
```

result equals your expected solution

```
ArcCos[Sqrt[2/3]]/(2 \[Pi]  )
% //N  (*0.0979566*)
```

Comment: It is not so simple. `SeedRandom[1234]; Maximize[expr, xt]` results in `{3 Csc[2 ArcTan[
Root[1 - 10 #^2 + #^4& , 3, 0]]] Sin[4 ArcTan[
Root[1 - 10 #^2 + #^4& , 3, 0]]]^2, {xt -> (-24 \[Pi] + ArcTan[
Root[1 - 10 #^2 + #^4& , 3, 0]])/\[Pi]}}` and then `N[%]` produces `{4.6188, {xt -> -23.902}}`.

Comment: Moreover, `NMaximize[expr^2, xt]` performs `{21.3333, {xt -> -0.902043}}`. See `Plot[{expr, expr^2}, {xt, 0, 1/2}]`.

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 `Maximize` and `NMaximize` both give the same numerical result, in accordance with the from QP expected result. No need to switch to the quadratic  maximization `NMaximize[expr^2, xt]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, t_] := 3 Csc[2 π x t] Sin[4 π x t]^2;

Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x, t], {t, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> {0, 5},
  GridLines -> {None, {8/Sqrt[3]}},
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed],
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04],
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {HoldForm@t, HoldForm@f})],
 {{x, 0.5}, 0.1, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {x}]
```

[image]

The maximum does not change with `x`

```
max = MaxValue[f[x, t], {x, t}] // FullSimplify

(* 8/Sqrt[3] *)

sol = MinimalBy[
    Solve[f[x, t] == max, t, Reals] /. C[1] -> 0,
    Last][[1]] // ToRadicals

(* {t -> ArcTan[Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]]/(π x)} *)
```

Equivalently,

```
sol2 = ResourceFunction["RadicalDenest"][sol]

(* t -> -(ArcTan[Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[3]]/(π x)) *)
```

Verifying,

```
(t /. sol) == (t /. sol2) // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Isn't a crucial step `C[1] -> 0` done by hand?

Comment: @user64494 - It is a means of specifying the base period.

Comment: Let us call the things by their proper names: `Solve[f[x, t] == max, t, Reals]` results in `{{{t -> ConditionalExpression[
    (2*ArcTan[Root[1 - 10*#1^2 + 
           #1^4 & , 3, 0]] + 
      2*Pi*C[1])/(2*Pi*x), 
    Element[C[1], Integers]]}, 
 {t -> ConditionalExpression[
    (2*ArcTan[Root[1 - 10*#1^2 + 
           #1^4 & , 4, 0]] + 
      2*Pi*C[1])/(2*Pi*x), 
    Element[C[1], Integers]]}}` and you choose `C[1]==0` by hand.

Comment: This is a crucial step. If you put `C[1]!=0` , you go to nowhere. Regard.